# Windows Defender says it has a recommendation about my device driver, but no recommendation is visible

Tags: windows-10

After a scan following the most recent Windows 10 update windows defender is showing an "issue" relating to my device driver. There is a message saying "1 recommendation" but when I click on it no recommendation appears. I therefore have no idea what the problem is or how to deal with it. Can anyone suggest a way to sort this out?

Comment: Its a false positive, ignore it for now.

Answer (score 0):

It could be just an issue with the security centre program.

I had a similar issue (after my machine hung) with the App and Software section. Clicking it had no effect other than to toggle the direction of the arrow.

I closed the program and re-ran it and this time it displayed more information - in this case that I should run the troubleshooter. There wasn't any problem (just Windows being weird again), but this could be the case for you as well.